# How to perform bitwise operation of binary numbers?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I need to do bitwise OR of two binary strings.

For example, if the binary strings are '110001' and '101101', then I need the result as '111101'.

I tried this, but it gave me strange results.

```
console.log(110001 | 101101);
```

Comment: Did you try `console.log((parseInt("110001", 2) | parseInt("101101", 2)).toString(2))`?

Comment: The logical OR Of one hundred and ten thousand and one, with one hundred and one thousand, one hundred and one ... what's strange, exactly?

Comment: @Pointy It's binary digit. Why do you feel strange?

Comment: @Tyler.z.yang JavaScript doesn't think those are binary digits. Those are plain base-10 numbers :)

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, what I mean is Foreever want to explain this into binary digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast the binary representation to it's int equivalent. (otherwise it's interpreted as 110001 (base 10)):

```
console.log((parseInt('110001',2) | parseInt('101101',2)).toString(2));
```

The output is then cast back to it's base 2 representation (string)

Answer (score 3):

You can't write binary numbers as literals in JavaScript. The only numeric literals allowed are:

1. Decimal: `1337` (One thousand and thirty-seven).
2. Octal: `02471` (One thousand and thirty-seven in base 8).
3. Hexadecimal: `0x539` (One thousand and thirty-seven in base 16).

To write binary numbers you need to use `parseInt` with base 2. To convert a number to binary representation you use `toString` with base 2. Hence you would write it as:

```
var a = parseInt("110001", 2);
var b = parseInt("101101", 2);
var c = a | b;

console.log(c.toString(2));
```

Simple.